# Use calculus to find minimum value of $S$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

$S = x^2/2 + (16000√2)/x$

I know I have to find the derivative and get the stationary points, then use the second derivative to find the one which gives a minimum value and then put that x value back into S to find the minimum value.

However, it seems like there are some issues with how I am differentiating because I keep getting absurd answers which I won't waste time outlining..

any advice?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the derivative of $S$ and set it to zero

$$S’=x-\frac{16000\sqrt2}{x^2}=0$$

or,

$$ x^3=16000\sqrt2$$

Solve for the extrema point at

$$x=20\sqrt2$$

$S(x)$ takes the minimum value at this point,

$$\frac{(20\sqrt2)^2}{2}+ \frac{16000\sqrt2}{20\sqrt2}=1200$$

We argue that 1200 is the minimum value since $S(x)$ goes to infinity when $x\rightarrow 0$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$. It can also be verified by examining the positivity of its second derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{16000\sqrt{2}}{x}$. We have that
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(2x)+\frac{-16000\sqrt{2}}{x^2}=x-\frac{16000\sqrt{2}}{x^2}.
$$
To find the extrema, we set $f'(x)=0$, so
$$
\begin{align*}
x-\frac{16000\sqrt{2}}{x^2}=0 &\iff x=\frac{16000\sqrt{2}}{x^2} \\
&\iff x^3=16000\sqrt{2} \\
&\iff x=20\sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, we find $f''(20\sqrt{2})$,
$$
f''(x)=1+\frac{32000\sqrt{2}}{x^3} \ \ \ \textrm{so} \ \ \ f''(20\sqrt{2})=3.
$$
Since $f''(20\sqrt{2})>0$, we know the function is concave up at $x=20\sqrt{2}$, thus $f(20\sqrt{2})=1200$ is a minimum of the function. If you look at the [graph of the function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hrbstkgkgv) though, it is pretty clear that the function only has a local minimum, not an absolute one, that is if you are considering the domain of $f$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer using AM-GM:

When $x < 0$, $f'(x) = x - \frac{16000 \sqrt2}{x^2}$ is always negative, so there is no local minimum there.

Therefore if the local minimum exists, it must exist when $x > 0$. Using AM-GM we have:

$$\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{8000 \sqrt{2}}{x} + \frac{8000 \sqrt{2}}{x} ≥ 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{2} \cdot \frac{8000 \sqrt{2}}{x} \cdot \frac{8000 \sqrt{2}}{x}}$$
$$≥ 3 \sqrt[3] {64 \ 000 \ 000}$$
$$≥ 1200$$